# Python RQ Jobs dispatched EARLIER than scheduled

Tags: python, datetime, redis

I'm seeing that jobs in scheduler get executed EARLIER than as defined in "enqueue_at".

I thought it was issue with UTC datetime, but that doesnt' seem to be the issue.

Not sure if this matters but I have multiple schedulers and multiple workers... (as recommended in the docs).

According to the [docs](https://python-rq.org/docs/scheduling/):

> Note that if you pass in a naive datetime object, RQ will automatically convert it to the local timezone.

However, comment in this python RQ scheduler repo says

> scheduler.enqueue_at(datetime(2020, 1, 1), func) # Date time should be in UTC

So I tried passing both UTC and "America/New_York" time but that doesn't seem to matter.

Example:

> At, 2020-08-25 21:51:00+00:00, I add 1 job to queue

[job 1] send_date: 2020-08-25 21:55:00+00:00

> At 2020-08-25 21:52:00+00:00, two things happen

I add 2 more jobs

- [job 1] send_date: 2020-08-25 21:55:00+00:00
- [job 2] send_date: 2020-08-25 22:00:00+00:00
- [job 3] send_date: 2020-08-25 22:05:00+00:00

Job 1 is launched

> At 2020-08-25 21:53:00+00:00

Job2 is launched

> At 2020-08-25 21:54:00+00:00

Job3 is launched

IN all cases, the jobs are launched AHEAD of their scheduled time

What am I missing here?

Comment: and where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening b/c i was passing naive datetime but RQ scheduler was expecting timezone aware datetime.